# Execution reverted: ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing in this contract below.

I get this error **`Execution reverted: ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved`** when I run the `createMarketItem` function.

The wallet holds 2 nfts and I want to put one for sale using this smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner == msg.sender;
    }

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 itemId;
        address nftContract;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;


    event MarketItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed itemId,
        address indexed nftContract,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price,
        bool sold
    );

    function createMarketItem(
        address nftContract, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price
    ) public payable nonReentrant {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");

        _itemIds.increment();
        uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();

        idToMarketItem[itemId] = MarketItem(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(0)),
            price,
            false
        );

        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

        emit MarketItemCreated(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            msg.sender,
            address(0),
            price,
            false
        );
    }

    function createMarketSale(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 itemId
    ) public payable nonReentrant {
        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
        bool sold = idToMarketItem[itemId].sold;
        require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
        require(sold != true, "This Sale has already finished");

        idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _itemsSold.increment();
        idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
    }

    function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 itemCount = _itemIds.current();
        uint256 unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)) {
                uint256 currentId = i + 1;
                MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice this part of the `createMarketItem` function:

`IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);`

It basically transfers your NFT from your wallet to this smart contract [`address(this)`].

But the thing is that smart contracts are not allowed to do this unless you give them permission.

For that you have to first call the `approve` function of your NFT contract to give this contract permission to move your NFT around.

This is the `approve` function:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L112

Just pass the `NFTMarketplace`  contract address and the tokenId in the `approve` function and then try to call the `createMarketItem`  function of the marketplace.